# How can I add a default text in my HTML input text

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I add a default text in my HTML text just like in the image below

[image]

Right now this is my html codes:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="guardian_officeno" placeholder="Office #" required pattern="[0-9].\d{8}|\d{11}" title="Only Numbers are accepted and must be 10 or 11 numbers"></td>
  </div>
```

EDIT:

How can I add text that cannot be erased

Answer (score 4):

As per the recent update of your question, you need to add `readonly` attribute to your `input` tag. If you are trying to disable part input, which is not possible, refer to last section of my answer.

```
<input type="text" value="SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE" readonly>
```

Adding `readonly` will prevent users to change the text in your `input` box.

> Note: Don't rely on `readonly` as it can be easily overridden using
>   dev tools. Make sure you do have server side checks for the same.

---

**Before you updated your question**

Add `value` attribute to your `input` tag if you want some default text in the `input` box

```
<input type="text" value="Default Val">
```

---

If you are talking about the prefix i.e country specific STD code like +63, then you can do is split up your `input` tags, and set a default value in the first tag and let your user write the number in the other tag.

Comment: is it possible to just do it in one input tag?

Comment: @adrianpascua no, you cannot keep part of your input text as readable and part editable. I assume you are talking about the last part which I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, with the tag value:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="guardian_officeno" placeholder="Office #" required pattern="[0-9].\d{8}|\d{11}" title="Only Numbers are accepted and must be 10 or 11 numbers"  value="default text"></td>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want to add a default text in "input" tag?
you need to add "value" attribute  in there!

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="guardian_officeno" placeholder="Office #" required pattern="[0-9].\d{8}|\d{11}" title="Only Numbers are accepted and must be 10 or 11 numbers" value="put your default text right here"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

input tag not support for before attribute in css, but you can using wrapper by other tags. look for example below:

html + css

```
<div class="input-row">
    Phone number:<span id="phoneNumber"><input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="" placeholder="1234567890"></span>
</div>
<style>
    .input-row {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 1;
    }
    span#phoneNumber::before {
        content: '+63';
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 1px;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    input[name='phoneNumber']{
        line-height: 18px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
</style>
```